# Installing wine mono and gecko using .msi file offline

Tags: windows, wine

How can i install wine mono and gecko? I have downloaded the .msi file suitable for installed wine version.
Please help me. Where shoul i place these .msi files?

Comment: Run them with Wine, perhaps? It's not a matter of where to place them.

Comment: wine could not run these .msi files??

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-users/2005-December/020055.html

```
wine msiexec /i <path to msi>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `wine-mono` in `/usr/share/wine/mon/`. I already did it and it's the location where wine is looking for it according to this [webpage](https://wiki.winehq.org/Mono).

The same for `wine_gecko` msi placed in`/usr/share/wine/gecko`.